# Angular 4 HTTP response exception app stops working

Tags: angular, api, get, crash, http-status-code-404

Everytime I ask the API http://api.zippopotam.us for a postal code that does not exists, my Angular 4 application crashes with the error 404 (Not Found). If I ask with a new postal code without refreshing the page, it doesn't work anymore.

My HTTP-GET looks like this:

```
getPlz(plz: string): Observable<City> {
    return this.http
      .get(`${this.api}/ch/${plz}`)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .map(rawCity => CityFactroy.fromObject(rawCity))
      .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try putting the `.catch` operator after the `.get`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that..